# How to write JESS defrule "if a value not exist in a list, then printout a warning"

Tags: conditional-statements, rule, not-exists, expert-system, jess

I am a newbie in JESS, and moderate in Java.

I have 'cList' as list of special commodities (include 'essential' and 'regional' commodities), 
and 'xList' as list of all commodities (include 'essential' and 'non-essential' commodities)
I want to make a rule: if 'x' from 'xList' with status 'essential' does not exist in 'cList' then print "Missing essential commodity 'x'."

To be clear, my systems's pattern is same as pricing_engine example in Jess71p2.

- cList as same as CatalogItems
- xList as same as OrderItems

I declare deftemplate from Java classes.
here's the deftemplate;

```
    (import com.aisy.entity.*)
    (deftemplate oldList(declare (from-class oldList)))
    (deftemplate xList  (declare (from-class xList)))
    (deftemplate cList  (declare (from-class cList)))
```

Here's the xList.java

```
    package com.aisy.entity;
    import java.sql.Timestamp;
    public class xList {
            private Long id_commodity;
            private String commodity;
            private String essentiality;
            private Timestamp update;

        public xList() {
            super();
        }

        public xList(Long id_commodity, String commodity, String essentiality, Timestamp update) {
            super();
            this.id_commodity = id_commodity;
            this.commodity = commodity;
            this.essentiality = essentiality;
            this.update = update;
        }

        public Long getId_commodity() {
            return this.id_commodity;
        }

        public void setId_Commodity(Long id_commodity) {
            this.id_commodity = id_commodity;
        }

        public String getCommodity() {
            return this.commoditty;
        }

        ....getter and setter methods for the rest fields
    }
```

Here's the cList.java;

```
    public class cList {
        private Long id_commodity;
        private String commodity;
        private String price;
        private Double final_price;

        public cList(Long id_commodity, String commodity, String price, Double final_price) {
            super();
            this.id_commodity = id_commodity;
            this.commodity = commodity;
            this.price = price;
            this.final_price = final_price;
        }

        public cList() {
            super();
        }

            ...common getter and setter methods for all fields
```

Here's warning.java;

```
    public class warning {
        private final String description;
        public warning(String aDescription) {
        description = aDescription;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
        return description;
        }
    }
```

Here's the defrule;

```
    (defrule 
       (xList (commodity ?essential_commodity) (essentiality /essential/))
       (not(cList (commodity ?essential_commodity)))
        => (add ( new warning "Missing essential commodity" ?essential_commodity))
    )
```

I try to put some information to Database for xList and cList:

```
    xList("100000", "PEANUT", "2.45");
    xList("100003", "BREAD", "1.5");

    cList("100000", "PEANUT", "ESSENTIAL");
    cList("100002", "CAKE", "ESSENTIAL");
    cList("100003", "BREAD", "NON ESSENTIAL" );
```

From that, if I run my rule engine, the result should be

```
   "Missing essential commodity 100002"
```

But my current result is:

```
    "Missing essential commodity 100000"
    "Missing essential commodity 100002"
```

How to write fix this?

> *edited: 07/22/2016 added xList.java and cList.java*

Comment: Perhaps you make a mistake while creating and inserting the facts. Can't tell without the code for that.

Answer (score 0):

The exact syntax depends, of course, on the exact nature of the facts you're matching. The below rule is written assuming that there are many "xList" facts, each listing the name of a commodity and its essentialness in the "commodity" and "essentiality" slots, respectively, and that there is just one cList fact which contains a list of all essential commodities. The blank multifields ("$?") match an arbitrary number of list elements before and after the essential commodity.

```
(defrule 
   (xList (commodity ?essential_commodity) (essentiality essential))
   (not (cList $? ?essential_commodity $?))
    =>
   (assert (warning
       (str-cat "Missing essential commodity" ?essential_commodity))))
```

Comment: Actualy, there'are many cList facts. All deftemplate are declared from java classes, so do the 'warning' is a class. I still get errors.

Answer (score 0):

Ernest was almost there:

```
(defrule 
   (xList (commodity ?essential_commodity) (essentiality essential))
   (not (cList (commodity ?essential_commodity)))
=>
   (assert (warning (description ?essential_commodity)))
)
```

Note: Calling classes "-List" that aren't lists and not even contain is disconcerting (and it sure confused Ernest). Classes should be called somethingCommodity, and field names might be restricted to "id", "name" etc.

Comment: I am sorry for my confusing example. Actually, I wrote classes and methods in non English language, therefore I replaced it in order to make you understand, but forget to consider those things. My system's pattern is same with pricing_engine example in Jess71p2. I've tried your code, and put the result on my post. But still, It doesnt solve my problem.

Comment: I added a missing pair of parentheses!  @Zsy, without the specific error messages, there's no way we can guess what's not working for you.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill Ah, it's good to have you look at my code. I'm beginning to lose my touch. :-]